# Accessing Sencha javascript files in Phonegap on Android

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I was able to run the Sencha Touch Application with Phonegap on Android Emulator 3.1.

But when it comes to an Android Tablet (Samsung Galaxy, 3.1), it was not able to load up the application. It comes up with an error in accessing *.js files generated by the sencha for Store, Model, View & Controller.

The Error is:

```
Failed loading 'app/store/xyz.js', please verify that the file exists
 Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'app/store/xyz.js', please verify that the file exists at file:///android_asset/www/sencha-touch-all-debug.js:8010
```

I am using Sencha Touch 2.0.0 and PhoneGap 1.7.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webview on Android v3.x and above is unable to load local files with parameters, see issue [#17535](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535) for details but in short, this won't work:

```
<a href="file:///android_assets/test.html?para=one>test</a>
```

The vicious consequence of this problem is that Sencha Touch 2 and particulary the [Ext.Loader](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Loader) and [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) classes are unable to load javascript dependencies due to the extra 'timestamp' parameter that is added to each javascript file (see [disableCachingParam](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Loader-cfg-disableCachingParam)).

To workaround this, you need to disable the 'disableCaching' option:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true, disableCaching: false });
Ext.Ajax.setDisableCaching(false);
```

See also bug [#TOUCH-1463](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?162322-Sencha-Touch-2-PhoneGap-are-not-working-on-Android-4)